# Passing a List from Servlet to JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, scriptlet

When I try to set the value of a list in Servlet to a session variable and access it JSP like,

**doGet**

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("MySessionVariable", authorizeUserList);
```

**JSP**

```
<%List lst = session.getAttribute("MySessionVariable");%>
```

I get an error in JSP as "List cannot be resolved to a type"

So how should I do this? I want to pass a list from Servlet to JSP and populate a Drop down.

Comment: [Scriptlets are since a decade discouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/). I recommend to learn taglibs/EL before it's too late. This way you also don't need those `import` statements anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you importing list and casting?

```
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<% List lst = (List) session.getAttribute("MySessionVariable"); %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast it to List as getAttribute return Object type.

Comment: The particular compilation error has completely nothing to do with casting. Whoever upvoted this answer should reconsider the upvote.

Comment: May I know the reason of downvoting it.

Comment: Which compilation error? Shyam has provided same solution as I suggested.

Comment: Are you new to Java? The *"List cannot be resolved to a type"* is a compilation error. You need to import the type. The cast only fixes the new problem which comes thereafter.

Comment: OK got it. I did not see it in terms of compilation like regular java.

Comment: `<% %>` in JSP is precisely regular Java.

Comment: but directly pass list attribute, it will cause a unchecked cast from object to list warning