# Send a List object from a Java Servlet to JSP using the PrintWriter object?

Tags: java, json, jsp, servlets

Before proceeding I realise that there's a similar question ([Passing a List from Servlet to JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16982516/passing-a-list-from-servlet-to-jsp)) from a couple of years ago. I realise that it is possible to set the list I'm trying to pass as a session attribute but out of curiosity I wondered if it's possible to use the PrintWriter object to send the data back to the JSP page.

**JSP**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function getEngineSchemes(engineID) {
            $.get('SchemeTypeServlet', {
                action: "getSchemes",
                engineID: engineID
            },
            function(data, status){

            }).fail(function() {
                alert("Error obtaining schemes for engine with engine id: " + engineID);
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

**Servlet**

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    //Set type of response
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    //get parameters that may be passed from client to determine which methods should be called
    String action = request.getParameter("action");

    if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("getSchemesForEngine")) { 
        Integer engineID = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("engineID"));
        List<String> schemeNames = getSchemeNamesForEngine(engineID);

        response.getWriter(). //insert code to send object back to JSP
        response.getWriter().flush();
    }
```

**Options**

One solution I think may be reasonable would be to create a `JSONObject` and have something along the lines of

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
     for(String name : schemeNames) {
            json.put(engineID, name);
         }
    response.getWriter().write(json.toJSONString());
    response.getWriter().flush();
```

I haven't tested the above code but I just want to know if that seems like the best solution to my problem or if I'm making it overly complicated? Maybe there's a far simpler solution to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having things messed up in your head. First of all, you cannot sent text or any kind of data from a servlet to a jsp. The proper way to do this is to use the session and use [response.sendRedirect](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect(java.lang.String)) or [RequestDispatcher.forward](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html) methods. But this will ignore any calls made before to the servlet's Writer Object.

Comment: Yes, you can send data from a Servlet back to the JSP page because I have done so already. In a JSP file you can include HTML and JavaScript and as such you can use JQuery.post() which allows you to specify a Servlet to post the data to, and in the callback function, for example: 
    ...
    }).done(function( data ) {
    var content = data[.json_identifier]
    $( "#result" ).val(content);
  });

you can utilise your results obtained from the Servlet to populate html elements.